# Show the whole world on iOS google maps App

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there an option to somehow zoom out more on a iOS app created with the new Google Maps sdk? Like showing the whole world for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GMSCameraPosition.h contains two consts

```
/**
 * The maximum zoom (closest to the Earth's surface) permitted by the map
 * camera.
 */
FOUNDATION_EXTERN const CGFloat kGMSMaxZoomLevel;

/**
 * The minimum zoom (farthest from the Earth's surface) permitted by the map
 * camera.
 */
FOUNDATION_EXTERN const CGFloat kGMSMinZoomLevel;
```

You can zoom out the furthest by saying:

```
self.googleMap.camera = [GMSCameraPosition    
cameraWithLatitude:self.googleMap.camera.target.latitude
longitude:self.googleMap.camera.target.longitude
zoom:kGMSMinZoomLevel
bearing:self.googleMap.camera.bearing
viewingAngle:self.googleMap.camera.viewingAngle];
```

if  self.googleMap is your GMSMapView.
(there might be a simpler way to do it, but this works)

There is no way to zoom out further  to see  3D globe or smtg.
You would need Google Earth for that.

Comment: Thanks, works. In swift: let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(self.mapView.camera.target.latitude, longitude: self.mapView.camera.target.longitude, zoom: kGMSMinZoomLevel, bearing: self.mapView.camera.bearing, viewingAngle: self.mapView.camera.viewingAngle)